# Directly modifying the state of a react component works reliably and consistently?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

While looking through the ReactJS code of a colleague, I noticed them "modifying the state directly". I also tried it out with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">

        class App extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {"message":""};
            }
            textChange(evt) {
                this.state.message = evt.currentTarget.value;
                this.setState({});
            }
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <p>{this.state.message}</p>
                        <input type="text" onChange={evt=>this.textChange(evt)} />
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The method `textChange(evt)` consistently and reliably updates the state.  I read in a few blogs on the internet that we **should not** be modify the state directly...did I misunderstand something?

Also consider all these other ways of modifying states:

```
textChange1(evt) {
    this.state.message = evt.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState(this.state);
}
textChange2(evt) {
    const state = this.state;
    state.message = evt.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState(state);
}
textChange3(evt) {
    const state = this.state;
    state.message = evt.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState({});
}
textChange4(evt) {
    this.setState({message:evt.currentTarget.value});
}
textChange5(evt) {
    let message = evt.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState({message});
}
```

Which of these is the idiomatic way to modify states in ReactJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that we should never modify state directly (unless it's in the constructor). Doing so may work, but will lead to unintended side effects.

> always create new objects and arrays when you call setState,

source: https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/

> Do Not Modify State Directly # <--- from react docs itself

source: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

In your example, the below 2 are the best/idiomatic ways to modify state. Note, when you use `{}` you are initializing an object literal (i.e. creating a new object), which is what the below 2 methods are doing (but that of course in and of itself does not mean it's correct, as you can see with `textChange3`).

```
// great
textChange4(evt) {
    this.setState({message:evt.currentTarget.value});
}
// great
textChange5(evt) {
    let message = evt.currentTarget.value; // note `let` should be `const` (style-wise) since you are not reassigning message, but otherwise this is fine!
    this.setState({message});
}
```

Breaking down each method with comments

```
// not good
textChange1(evt) {
    this.state.message = evt.currentTarget.value; // modifying original state object
    this.setState(this.state);
}
// not good
textChange2(evt) {
    const state = this.state; // this is the exact same as above,
    // except you aliased this.state as state.
    state.message = evt.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState(state);
}
// not good
textChange3(evt) {
    const state = this.state;
    state.message = evt.currentTarget.value; // same problem as above of modifiying state directly
    this.setState({}); // you might expect the state to be set to an empty object, but it's not
    // in this case it's basically a no-op because state updates are merged. see https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
}
// great
textChange4(evt) {
    this.setState({message:evt.currentTarget.value});
}
// great
textChange5(evt) {
    let message = evt.currentTarget.value; // note `let` should be `const` (style-wise) since you are not reassigning message, but otherwise this is fine!
    this.setState({message});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, based on yoru answer, I just realized how messy it could get to setState of deeply nested properties as described in this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react .  Yikes........